# AngularJS: How to show the status of a long process that is happening in the server to the user?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

First of all, let me tell you I am quite new to AngularJS.

I have a button on my AngularJS page. When pressed it asks the server (ASP.Net Application) to do a process which takes about 40-80 seconds to complete. The process returns status about the process every second or so using the `response.Flush`.

I wanted to show the status to the user on a popup window with the text passed to the front-end on real time. Is this possible on a AngularJS page.

This is my AngularJS html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html ng-app="myapp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="r_Div3_MainContent" ng-view>
     </div>
     <script src="codes/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl : 'partials/Home.htm',
    controller  : 'HomeController'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
});
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope){
// include the code to send the request to the server and show the status...
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is your asp.net application MVC or-it is a web API?

Comment: I am using Web API. For certain reasons I am still using Visual Studio 2008.